# accessing variable like this MainForm.property , without instantiating MainForm mf = new MainForm;

Tags: c#

```
Form1 {
       public int VAR;
       public  int PRTY_VAR
       { 
         get { return VAR; }   set { VAR= value; } 
       }

}
```

---

```
 Form2
    {
        private void trackBar2_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             // here, cant access property "PRTY_VAR"
             Form1.PRTY_VAR= 1 + trackBar2.Value;

        }

     }
```

cant access PRTY_VAR from form2 . i need to change VAR without deaclaring

`MainForm mf = new MainForm;`   in Form2 ,

because declaring it doesnt change the varible on MainForm. 
it only changes the newly created MainForm instance's variable.(which is not THE real MainForm.)

thanks.

edit: shoud i play with the Application.Run(new Form1());   in program.cs to make it public

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options:

1. Pass a reference of `MainForm` to `Form2` and access it from there.
2. Make the property static on `MainForm`.

I prefer **Option 1**, because I don't like the idea of having static properties floating around for just anyone to change.  It can also introduce awkward threading problems.  But it sounds like **Option 2** is closer to what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks adding static to variable 'public static int VAR;' this let me access it from form2.

Comment: @blackholeearth0_gmail Good deal. Be aware that if you take this pattern too far (and do it too often), your code will become spaghetti and difficult to debug/maintain.

Comment: pass a refence , you mean; f2.open(this);  is this the thing called passing a reference? thanks.

Comment: @blackholeearth0_gmail You can do it many ways... Selman22's way will work, or you could do `f2 = new Form2(this)` and just have `Form2`'s constructor take a `Form` argument.  I think that would be easier to follow/maintain.

Answer (score 1):

When opening your `Form2` pass your current form instance like this:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.open(this);
```

Then you can access your variable from `Form2:`

```
// Owner represents your main form, we are making cast to access PRTY_VAR property
((Main_Form)Owner).PRTY_VAR= 1 + trackBar2.Value;
```